# How to get the value of checkboxes in the order they are selected?

Tags: javascript

hope you can help me :)
I have this code to get the value of the checkboxes:

```
 function check() {
     var Input = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxes:checked")).map(function(el) {
         return el.value;

     }).join(',')

     document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = Input;
     return false;
 }
```

I want that the output is in the order I selected the checkboxes. Is there a way to get them in correct order?

Comment: When you change their value, set the timestamp property to them so that when you fetch them from DOM you can sort them in the order of selection. Please share your markup.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` always returns the nodes in document tree order. If you want to sort them differently, you need to keep the list of values yourself, and append/remove to it on `change` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **set the timestamp** to them when they are changed (*comments inline*)

```js
var allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'][data-name]");

//bind the event to set time value on change
[...allCheckboxes].forEach(s => s.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  e.currentTarget.timeval = new Date().getTime();
}));

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", check);

function check() {
  var output = [...allCheckboxes] 
    .filter(s => s.checked) // filter out non-checked
    .sort((a, b) => a.timeval - b.timeval) //sort by timeval
    .map(s => s.getAttribute("data-name")).join(","); //fetch only data-name for display

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
Check 1 <input type="checkbox" data-name="check1"> <br/> Check 2 <input type="checkbox" data-name="check2"> <br/> Check 3 <input type="checkbox" data-name="check3"> <br/> Check 4 <input type="checkbox" data-name="check4"> <br/> Check 5 <input type="checkbox"
  data-name="check5"> <br/>

<button>check</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answers. This one worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set an array and save the values as they are selected.

You can achive this by giving each chcekbox an event listener.

In the event listener you add an if to validate if the click event was when checked and then add them to your list/array.

Hope this helps :)

```js
var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var order = [];

for(var i=0; i<checks.length;i++){
  checks[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(this.checked)
      order.push(this.value);
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="A">A
<input type="checkbox" value="B">B
<input type="checkbox" value="C">C
<input type="checkbox" value="D">D
<br>
<button onclick="console.log('Order: '+order)">Check order</button>
```

Comment: This does not work if user deselects one or more checkbox(s), since array (order) is not cleaned and re-built.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data-id attribute to each section. And when you click on one checkbox, change the attribute values of each checkbox to a serial number. To do this, it's easier to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and add or delete depending of the checked state of the check box.

Set returns the items in insertation order.

```js
var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'),
    order = new Set,
    i

for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    checks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        order[['delete', 'add'][+this.checked]](this.value);
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="A">A
<input type="checkbox" value="B">B
<input type="checkbox" value="C">C
<input type="checkbox" value="D">D
<br>
<button onclick="console.log('Order: '+[...order])">Check order</button>
```